# Best way to insert csv in mysql database

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a csv file with apr. 6000 rows like this:

```
female>gifts>bags;red;gucci;http:\/\/blabla.com;2334.56
```

I want to import this into a mysql db, but split the first csv field into three single values. This values and color and brand should go into own tables, rest of the product has a product table and has only the brand, color etc id from the additional tables.

But importing the csv means checking for every row all values in the additional tables, returning the id or insert if necessary and then returning the id.

Result would be 5 Select operations and one Insert. 
Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: What stops you from writing trivial PHP script that would iterate over `fgetcsv()` and do those `5 SELECT operations and INSERT`?

Comment: It will take to much time to read all data and I think it is to much load for the server. I'm looking for an optimized approach